# Difference between javascript operator === and lodash method _.eq()?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, comparison, lodash

Is there a difference between the === comparator in javascript and the _.eq() method in lodash?

**_.eq()** ([Link](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#eq))

> Performs a SameValueZero comparison between two values to determine if
>   they are equivalent.

**Update**

Not sure if this checks on the same type, like the === operator.

> 7.2.10SameValueZero (x, y)#
>
> The internal comparison abstract operation SameValueZero(x, y), where
>   x and y are ECMAScript language values, produces true or false. Such a
>   comparison is performed as follows:
>
> If Type(x) is different from Type(y), return false. If Type(x) is
>   Number, then If x is NaN and y is NaN, return true. If x is +0 and y
>   is -0, return true. If x is -0 and y is +0, return true. If x is the
>   same Number value as y, return true. Return false. Return
>   SameValueNonNumber(x, y). NOTE SameValueZero differs from SameValue
>   only in its treatment of +0 and -0.
>
> 7.2.11SameValueNonNumber (x, y)#
>
> The internal comparison abstract operation SameValueNonNumber(x, y),
>   where neither x nor y are Number values, produces true or false. Such
>   a comparison is performed as follows:
>
> Assert: Type(x) is not Number. Assert: Type(x) is the same as Type(y).
>   If Type(x) is Undefined, return true. If Type(x) is Null, return true.
>   If Type(x) is String, then If x and y are exactly the same sequence of
>   code units (same length and same code units at corresponding indices),
>   return true; otherwise, return false. If Type(x) is Boolean, then If x
>   and y are both true or both false, return true; otherwise, return
>   false. If Type(x) is Symbol, then If x and y are both the same Symbol
>   value, return true; otherwise, return false. Return true if x and y
>   are the same Object value. Otherwise, return false.

Comment: perhaps the [documentation linked to by SameValueZero](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-samevaluezero) will help

Comment: 2a. from that link - `If x is NaN and y is NaN, return true` - so, no just that one statement makes it different to `===` - because `NaN !== NaN`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loadash `_.eq` checks the `NaN` equality as well.

`_.eq(NaN, NaN)` => true

`NaN === NaN` => false

https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/6cb3460fcefe66cb96e55b82c6febd2153c992cc/eq.js#L32

```
function eq(value, other) {
  return value === other || (value !== value && other !== other)
}
```